# HTML5 local storage offline cache is not working in Google AppEngine app

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine

i'm trying to use HTML5 local storage offline cache to store images locally but unable to cache it properly, im using manifest configuration in my HTML, here is the sample code for it.

in server i have created "test.appcache" file with below configuration.

CACHE MANIFEST
/images/*.*

but it is unable to cache content locally, if i see the network tab in chrome/firefox the status code of images were 304 with offline cache configuration and without this configuration. my application is landed in Google AppEngine platform.

Please let me know where it went wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Consider editing your question to include your appengine-web.xml and any other code that deals with the appcache. It may give more insight into what you're missing.

Comment: I have below configuration in my app.

Comment: I have below configuration in my app.

JSP
   <html manifest="test.appcache">

test.appcache
 
     CACHE MANIFEST 
     /images/*

web.xml

     <mime-mapping> <extension>manifest</extension> <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type> </mime-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Just creating a manifest isn't enough - you have to make sure you're serving it up (by adding it as a static resource in your App Engine configuration), and reference the manifest from your HTML, as documented [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

Comment: And you need to declare `mime_type: test/cache-manifest` so that the browser gets the mime type it expects.

Comment: i tried declaring mime type in web.xml of appengine app, but it didn't work for me 
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>manifest</extension>
 <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

Comment: @Naresh Have you followed all the other steps required? Can you fetch the manifest on the URL defined? What mimetype is it being served as?

Comment: Sorry for late reply :)

i loaded manifest file directly and it is showing proper content type as text/cache-manifest, but the time taken for images are same like rendering from server. is there anyway i can confirm it is stored in local machine ( Mac OS )?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with same issue and finally got it to work. Needed to add both of these handlers to app.yam. Also note that Chrome console will automatically debug your appcache - big help.

---

runtime: php55
handlers:

[image]